# Using p5.js, is it possible to draw a class that draws sub-classes within itself? For example, a 4x4 block made up of 1x1 blocks

Tags: javascript, angularjs, p5.js

I'm attempting to make a Tetris-like game, where the game's pieces are all made up of smaller pieces that share properties.

Currently I have:

```
    export class SquareTetromino {
      [x: string]: any;
      constructor(x, y, w, h) {
      ...
      }

      show(p5) {
         p5.push();
         p5.translate(this.posX, this.posY);
         p5.fill("#D8B6FF")
         p5.rect(0,0,this.w, this.h);
         p5.pop();

      }
     ...
    }
```

and:

```
    export class BlockTetromino {
      [x: string]: any;
      constructor(x, y, w, h) {
      ...
      }

      test(p5) {
          this.testArray.push(new SquareTetromino(this.posX,this.posY,this.w,this.h));
          this.testArray.push(new SquareTetromino(this.posX - 50,this.posY,this.w,this.h));
          this.testArray.push(new SquareTetromino(this.posX - 50,this.posY + 50,this.w,this.h));
          this.testArray.push(new SquareTetromino(this.posX,this.posY + 50,this.w,this.h));
      }

      show(p5) {
          p5.push();
          this.testArray.forEach((block) => {
            block.show(p5)
          })
          p5.pop();

      }
    }
```

And from my main component:

```
  s.setup = () => {

  ...

            bodies.push(new BlockTetromino(200,-50,50,50))
            bodies[0].test(s);
  ...
          }

  s.draw = () => {
         ...


          for (let i = 0; i < bodies.length; i++) {
            bodies[i].show(s)
          }
```

I'd like to be able to have a class Block which draws a small block, and then call that Block within a class Square, which draws 4 small blocks. Then, by instantiating Square I'll have 4 blocks chained together as one object.

I think I'm missing a for loop somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gave it a go and came up with this. It's somewhat rudimentary, but it think it can help as a starting point.

```js
class BuildingBlock{
 constructor(x, y, size, color){
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.size = size;
  this.color = color || 'red';
  this.display();
 }

 display(){
  fill(this.color);
  rect(this.x, this.y, this.size, this.size);
 }
}

class Polyomino{
 constructor(x, y, shape, blockSize){
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.shape = shape;
  this.blockSize = blockSize;
 }

 display(){
  for(let i = 0; i < this.shape.length; i++)
   for(let j = 0; j < this.shape[i].length; j++)
    if(this.shape[i][j] === 1)
     new BuildingBlock(this.x + (j*this.blockSize), this.y + (i*this.blockSize), this.blockSize);
 }
}

function setup(){
 createCanvas(400, 400);
 background(125);

 let pmShape = [
  [1, 1, 0, 1],
  [0, 1, 0, 1],
  [0, 1, 0, 1],
  [1, 1, 1, 1],
 ]
 let  p = new Polyomino(20, 20, pmShape, 30);
 p.display();

        let tmShape = [
            [1, 1, 0],
            [0, 1, 1]
        ];
        let tetromino = new Polyomino(200, 20, tmShape, 50);
        tetromino.display();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.7.3/p5.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 
</body>
</html>
```

The polyomino class should be able to handle the subset of tetrominoes; just define the shapes as matrices.